# How would one specify which containers to start and not to start in docker-compose? (docker run vs docker create)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In the [following guide](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/) when establishing how to make data-only docker containers they use the docker create command:

```
docker create -v /dbdata --name dbdata training/postgres /bin/true
```

However, as far as I know, with docker-compose you can only run containers not just create them. Is there any way to currently to use `docker create` in place of `docker run` for certain containers?

Moreover are there any negative consequences to running a data-only container instead of simply creating it?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You could create the single containers before orchestrating them with `docker-compose`.

Comment: @Smutje that defeats the purpose of using docker-compose to automate the creation of containers. I'm wondering if there is an option to specify if the container should only be created and not run.

Comment: When I specify data-only containers in a `docker-compose.yml`, they are only created and not run by docker.

Comment: @Smutje that seems to be what I'm missing. How do you specify a container is data-only in docker-compose?

Comment: Nothing special, just something similar to the following:
`postgres-data:
  image: ubuntu:latest
  container_name: postgres-data-container
  volumes:
   - /var/lib/postgresql/data`

Comment: @Smutje Ah I see now how that works for you. That container would be run and then would exit, but that's different than not having it run in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the best way seems to be addressed by these two github issue threads:

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/942
https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/1754

The addition of an option that doesn't run the containers is still under debate, but the solution for now seems to be to manually stop the container after running it

```
docker-compose <container-name> stop
```

You can also change the entrypoint in the .yml file to /bin/true if you don't want to deal with manually stopping it.

Comment: Can't you just set the CMD to `echo dc` or some such? Then the container would just exit by itself. Not sure if that will upset compose though.

Comment: @AdrianMouat yeah I eventually ended up doing that, but it starts it and then it exits because the command inside dies. There's no option to just not start it in the first place.

Comment: To be honest, Compose doesn't work very well with persistent data full stop atm. I'd recommend keeping data-containers outside of compose. It should be easier when the new volume command lands.

Comment: @AdrianMouat I agree. I do record the [path of a data container](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/8611c485e3515b33ef546b807cf880b20b6153da/updateDataContainerPath#L9), that way, even if I remove it (`docker rm` without the `-v` option), I still can [move that old path to the new data container](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/8611c485e3515b33ef546b807cf880b20b6153da/updateDataContainerPath#L35-L42).